# Why when I format a double it returns me with a comma?

Tags: java

When I format a double number it returns me with a comma, but I need it to return with a period. By the way I'm with the IDE NetBeans

```
double importe = (catidad * precioUnit);
System.out.println("double : " + importe);

System.out.println("double : " + String.format("%.2f", importe));

System.out.format("double : %.2f", importe);
```

returns:

```
run:
double : 5.699999999999999

double : 5,70

double : 5,70
```

I want you to return me with a point

Comment: What's your machine's locale?

Comment: It is formatting to the default locale. Given the other spellings, I'm assuming that a comma would be normally appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

that depends on the local formatting

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
System.out.println(String.format(Locale.US, "%f", 3.141592));
```

Comment: Thanks friend for the help.